# msbuild: Anyway to show summary and use verbosity=minimal

Tags: msbuild

I have a batch file for building .net solutions and am trying to get the verbosity level to be minimal which only shows which project is building and any warnings and/or errors but would also like to see the summary at the end with number of warnings and errors plus the build time.

I have tried multiple combinations of verbosity and /v and /cpl but it seems you can only get too much output + summary or right minimal output and no summary

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've also attempted this mamny ways and don't think it's possible... Out of curiosity, what's wrong with the standard output?  I've found it's very helpful in debugging build issues and can easily be wiped away with a 'cls' call

Comment: @NickNieslanik The standard output for the solution is large, and the command prompt buffer is not (without modification) large enough to allow you review the full console output, plus alot of the output such as copied file, deleted file I am not interested in

Comment: Why don't you use the File Logger remedy the command prompt buffer issue?  that would alleviate at least one of the issues.  You can use the file logger to do things like "log errors to one file, warnings to another, and regular info to a 3rd"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom logger as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171471.aspx

Here's a bit of code to get you started:

```
public class SummaryLogger : Logger
{
    int warningCount = 0;
    int errorCount = 0;

    public override void Initialize(IEventSource eventSource)
    {
        eventSource.WarningRaised += eventSource_WarningRaised;
        eventSource.ErrorRaised += eventSource_ErrorRaised;
        eventSource.BuildFinished += eventSource_BuildFinished;
    }

    void eventSource_WarningRaised(object sender, BuildWarningEventArgs e)
    {
        warningCount++;
        Console.WriteLine("Warning: " + e.Message);
    }

    void eventSource_ErrorRaised(object sender, BuildErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        errorCount++;
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    }

    void eventSource_BuildFinished(object sender, BuildFinishedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MSBuild Finished: " + errorCount + " errors | " + warningCount + " warnings.");
    }
}
```

This logger logs Warnings, Errors and Summarises the amount of errors and warnings. You'll need to add a little bit of code for time and projects, so that it is exactly what you want.

To use it, you call MSBuild with the following params added to it:

```
/nologo /noconsolelogger /logger:pathTo/SummaryLogger.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

one thought would be to extract required info from a log file.

Like this,

```
Step 1: Redirect your msbuild outputs to a log.txt
Step 2: At the end of the batch file run findstr cmd to look for desired text
```

Example:

```
@echo off
setlocal
...
MSBuild /nologo [path to project1 or sln1] [options] >> log.txt
...
MSBuild /nologo [path to project2 or sln2] [options] >> log.txt
...
findstr /irc:"Build*" /c:".*Warning(s)" /c:".*Error(s)" /c:"Time Elapsed.*" log.txt
```

Hope this helps!